# I want to create pagination for my custom post type archive that i am displaying with loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination, paginate-links

I have created a home.php file and in that i am showing my custom post type "projects with the WP-Query".
I have  added pagination to my custom post type using "paginate_links()" and the list shows up but when you click them error not found is shown. here is the code for the loop i am using:

```
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'projects',
     'posts_per_page' => 3,
     'paged'=> $paged,
     'order_by' => 'date',
                );
      $projects = new WP_Query( $args );

      while( $projects -> have_posts() ): $projects -> the_post();
  ///////// the content of the post types
       endwhile;
```

and this is the code I am using for the pagination links:

```
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
  echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $projects->max_num_pages
                ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this way:
add the following before $args

```
        if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ):
            $my_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        else:
            if( get_query_var( 'page' ) ):
                $my_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
        else:
                $my_page = 1;
        endif;
        $paged = $my_page;
```

Replace pagination code with this(make sure to add this after `endwhile`):

```
$total = $projects->found_posts;
            $page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['page'] ) : 1;
            $format = 'page/%#%/';
            $current_page = max(1, $paged);
            $big = 999999999;
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
                'end_size'           => 1,
                'mid_size'           => 2,
                'prev_next'          => True,
                'prev_text'          => 'prev',
                'next_text'          => 'next',
                'type'               => 'plain',
                'add_args'           => False,
                'add_fragment'       => '',
                'before_page_number' => '',
                'after_page_number'  => '',
                'total' => ceil($total / $posts_per_page),
                'current' => $current_page,
            ));
```